# How to update the number of topic partitions on dcos-kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I'm using DCOS-kafka on Mesos and I cannot figure out how to update the number of partitions for a topic.  It seems that you can update the topic using

```
dcos kafka update [topic-name] [parameter]=[value]
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out what the parameter for updating the number of partitions would be.  Is it even possible?